# How to get grep command output with a few lines?

Tags: grep

Now I'm using next command, to get a list files, which contains "random_string":

```
grep -l random_string *.txt
```

I want to get not only filenames, but also a few lines after(and may be - before) input.

So I want something like this as output:

```
file1.txt
    random_string
    ....
    ....
    random_string
    ....
    ....
file2.txt
    ....
```

Comment: Use the `-A` and `-B` options with grep, e.g. `grep -A 2 -B 2 ...`.

Comment: I do this "grep --after-context=10 -l some_string *.py" - but as an output get just filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ok. I got it.

Just need too replace -l option for -A or -B or -C(it's for results as both of A and B).

```
grep --after-context=10 some_string *.py
```